# Spinner popup background color issue

Tags: android, android-spinner

The following code produces an issue (see attached images) on Asus Intel Zenfone. Every other device I tested on is showing it fine, meaning the black area around the `Spinner` popup is transparent.

Any way to get rid of black color? I have `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` applied to the `Activity`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:popupBackground="@color/light_primary" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I face the same problem,finally i got solution.You need to create one xml file in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#606d73" />
</shape>
```

and then apply it to the spinner:

```
<Spinner
 android:id="@+id/from_spinner"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/refine_drpdn_right"
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
 android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_popup_background"
 android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Comment: If you are still facing the issue, adding `<corners android:radius="4dp" />` inside the drawable resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this issues, Simple, You only add a attribute as followings:

```
android:popupElevation="0dp"
```

Comment: Which is the function of that popupElevation property in a spinner? Anyway, I don't see any change if I change it to 0dp, and why 0dp? Which is its default value then? I think the default valur is 0dp but you overrided it on any parent style