# Android Spinner shows extra border

Tags: android

I have created an activity with spinner control and I want to style it.

XML :

```
<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spin_inch"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:popupBackground="@color/orange"
  android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Java :

```
spin_inch = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_inch);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_inch= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.inch_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter_inch.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

[image]

Could someone please let me know how to remove this extra border?

Comment: check [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425697/spinner-popup-background-color-issue), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721120/changing-spinner-background-generates-dark-colored-border)

Comment: remove popupBackground code and it should work.

Comment: @virajs Can you check if my answer is working?

Answer (score 0):

Try using match_parent on layout_width

```
     <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spin_inch"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:popupBackground="@color/orange"
     android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context by explaining how your answer solve the problem in question, instead of posting code-only answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your `layout_width` and `layout-height` properties in XML.

Change them to `wrap_content` both

```
<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spin_inch"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:popupBackground="@color/orange"
  android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

You've used `layout_weight` also, so if you've applied `weightSum` in parent of `Spinner`, apply `0dp` to respective property in `Spinner`. For example, if your `Orientation` is **Horizontal** with `weightSum` applied, you should apply `0dp` in `layout_width` in `Spinner`. Else, if your `Orientation` is **Vertical** with `weightSum` applied, you should apply `0dp` in `layout_height` in `Spinner`.