# changing Spinner Background add wierd dark border on popup on api 24 but works fine on latest android versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

here is my code

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinnerstudent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:popupBackground="@android:color/white" />
```

Spinner Item Code
'''

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="inherit" />
```

'''

this adds dark border on popup, do someone Know how to remove that border on api 24 (works fine on latest API versions)

Comment: This might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425697/spinner-popup-background-color-issue

Comment: applied both answers, not seems to work...   I changed spinnerMode to dialog for now that not show dark border but show items as Dialogue... any help will be appreciated.. thanks

Comment: you found the solution for this?